# Do I have to isolate my wsgi.py from my django project folder?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

where should I place my wsgi.py?
Do I have to isolate it from my django project folder?
Should I move my django project folder outside of my home directory?

Currently I copied my django project folder to /home/username/djangosites/project/
and my wsgi.py is in the folder /home/username/djangosites/project/project/
In the same folder there are files like settings.py urls.py ...

From the modwsgi documentation:

> "Note that it is highly recommended that the WSGI application script
>   file in this case NOT be placed within the existing DocumentRoot for
>   your main Apache installation, or the particular site you are setting
>   it up for. This is because if that directory is otherwise being used
>   as a source of static files, the source code for your application
>   might be able to be downloaded.
>
> You also should not use the home directory of a user account, as to do
>   that would mean allowing Apache to serve up any files in that account.
>   In this case any misconfiguration of Apache could end up exposing your
>   whole account for downloading.
>
> It is thus recommended that a special directory be setup distinct from
>   other directories and that the only thing in that directory be the
>   WSGI application script file, and if necessary any support files it
>   requires."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let wsgi.py but don't make DocumentRoot anything like /home/username/djangosites/project/ which would expose your Python scripts source code, which would definitely be very helpful to malicious users.

All you need to expose is STATIC_ROOT (on STATIC_URL) and MEDIA_ROOT (on MEDIA_URL), you can use the Alias directive for that. Another solution is to use dj-static.

Comment: Alias /static /home/username/djangosites/project/project/static/ can the static folder be a subfolder of home? And is it possible/useful to disable the DocumentRoot? Or why do I need it?

Comment: You do not need the DocumentRoot. You just need an Alias on STATIC_URL to STATIC_ROOT. Make sure you don't have anything unnecessary.